# XML Unmarshal getting tripped up by parallel tag

Tags: xml, go, rss

I'm working on an RSS reader application and running into an issue with The New York Times RSS feed. I've narrowed the issue down to the following XML (unnecessary fields omitted):

```
<item>
  <link>https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/25/briefing/nfl-angela-merkel-iraqi-kurdistan.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss</link>
  <atom:link rel="standout" href="https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/25/briefing/nfl-angela-merkel-iraqi-kurdistan.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss"/>
  <pubDate>Mon, 25 Sep 2017 13:36:07 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

I'm trying to parse it into the following structure:

```
type item struct {
    Link    string `xml:"link"`
    PubDate string `xml:"pubDate"`
}
```

When parsed, the Link field is blank. However, by deleting the atom:link field it works fine. I think the similarity in the tags names is confusing the parser. I have a go playground that demonstrates the issue, and that removing that line fixes it: https://play.golang.org/p/fUbLhSbo5K
How can I work around this issue? It's not really feasible to special case it because there could be other feeds that do this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long-standing [documentation bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11735) in Go's `encoding/xml` package. Basically, when you don't specify a namespace, the field will match *any* namespace instead of *no* namespace. In fact, there is no way to make a field match *only* when there is no namespace. If your XML has a namespace, the solution is to explicitly set it:

```
<item xmlns="foo">
  <link>https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/25/briefing/nfl-angela-merkel-iraqi-kurdistan.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss</link>
  <atom:link rel="standout" href="https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/25/briefing/nfl-angela-merkel-iraqi-kurdistan.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss"/>
  <pubDate>Mon, 25 Sep 2017 13:36:07 GMT</pubDate>
</item>

type item struct {
    Link    string `xml:"foo link"`
    PubDate string `xml:"pubDate"`
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/L9WOhixTKa.

If your `link` element explicitly *doesn't* have a namespace, you'll probably have to roll out your own `UnmarshalXML` method.